# Test application on multiple desktop platforms

Tags: testing, virtual-machine, desktop, multiplatform

Does anyone know of a website that allows me to create virtual machines with various versions of Windows, Mac OS, and Linux and VNC into them, so I can test an application on multiple platforms? (with a paid subscription, of course)

If only DigitalOcean provided Windows and Mac Droplets it would be just what I'm looking for.

If none exists you can thank me for the idea :)